# Problema Paginação X.PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou tentando implementar a paginação X.PagedList, mas nessa linha:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action(
    "Index", new { pagina, search = ViewBag.Busca }))
```

estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> 'IHtmlHelper<StaticPagedList<ApplicationClient>> ' não contém uma definição para 'PagedListPager' e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão 'PagedListPager' acessível que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo 'IHtmlHelper<StaticPagedList<ApplicationClient>> ' (há uma diretiva de uso ou referência de assembly ausente?)

saberiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Solução para quem precisar mudar `@using X.PagedList.Mvc` para `@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core` na view